# Linear Algebra: Matrices Contained in Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I am not sure I understand this question:

> Describe the smallest subspace of the matrix space M that contains:
>
> $$ \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}   1&0\\   0&0 \end{array} \right] $$
>
> and $$ \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}   0&1\\   0&0 \end{array} \right] $$

The answer is:

> All matrices
>
> $$ \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}   a&b\\   0&0 \end{array} \right] $$

Why is it not
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
  a&a\\
  0&0
\end{array}
\right] $$, since the two column values of both matrices contain 1's?

Comment: What if I take $a$ times first matrix plus $b$ times second matrix? Your question is basically to smallest subspace (i.e. span) of $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$.

Comment: Oh okay, that makes perfect sense now. Thank you!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been solved by comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because neither $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ nor $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ is of the form $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}a&a\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ for some number $a$. On the other hand, if $a,b\in\Bbb R$, then$$a\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}+b\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$So, every subspace of $\Bbb R^{2\times2}$ to which both $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ and $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ belong must contain every matrix of the form $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$. On the other hand, the matrices of this type form a subspace of $\Bbb R^{2\times2}$, and therefore the smallest subspace of $\Bbb R^{2\times2}$ containing $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ and $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ is the space of the matrices of the form $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.